# Jquery attribute value for current element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find value of an attribute for clicked element. All elements are dynamically populated.

I am unable to get value of attribute. what may be the issue?

```
<span title="cancel work" class="cancel" myid="111"><i class="fa fa-stop"></i> Stop work</span>

$(document).on('click','.cancel',(function(){
    alert(this.attr("myid"));
}));
```

This is the error message I get

> Object doesn't support property or method 'attr'

Comment: Should be `".cancel"` and not just `"cancel"`.

Comment: sorry for the type. I updated.

Comment: Avoid making up your own attributes. Use custom data attributes instead. Ex: `data-myid="111"`. And the code you posted after you corrected it, works https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ttc3surx/

Comment: [Your code works if you've got the `.` there.](https://jsfiddle.net/peqoqd4b/)

Comment: The error you're getting means that `$(this)` isn't returning a jQuery object. Are you sure you have jQuery loaded properly? I'm not sure how `$(document).on()` could be working if you don't, but something's wrong with jQuery in your page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myid` is not a valid HTML attribute. Most conventions resort to using custom attributes like this by implementing `data` attributes instead. For example, `data-myid`

```
<span title="cancel work" class="cancel" data-myid="111"><i class="fa fa-stop"></i> Stop work</span>

$(document).on('click','.cancel',(function(){
  alert($(this).data("myid"));
}));
```

Notice the changes:

- I'm using `data-myid` in the `span`
- I'm getting its value by using jQuery's `data` method.

Comment: The `.attr()` function will definitely retrieve the value of his attribute; see the jsfiddle link in the comment I just added to the question.

Comment: I understood the issue it should be $(this). and I just used this.

Comment: I thought both data-myid and myid are same. What makes more difference?

Comment: @Chandana `data-` attributes are a way of creating custom attributes and ensuring it remains valid HTML.

Comment: All this is true, but it has absolutely nothing to do with the error he's getting. It's not even calling `.attr()` because it says that the object has no such method.

Comment: He was calling it with `this` instead of `$(this)`. The valid HTML attribute information is just a bonus